# Azure - customErrors="off" in web.config is not displaying detailed errors in Azure app (cloud service)

Tags: azure, web-config, adfs2.0, custom-errors

I have an app deployed to Azure and it uses ADFS (Active Directory Federated Services) for authentication.

When the user tries to navigate to the app on Azure, it redirects the user to the ADFS authentication page.  User enters their credentials and clicks OK, and ADFS redirects the user to the landing page of my app.

Everything is working fine up to this point.  I'm getting a generic server error on the app once the user hits the landing page.  **PROBLEM: I need to see the detailed errors.**  I try setting `<customErrors="off" />`, repackage my app and redeploy, but that doesn't give me detailed errors:

[image]

Here's what I've tried: I've tried packaging my app in Debug mode (after Release mode didn't work), I've edited both web.config's (in the root of the solution, as well as in the Views folder, just to cover all bases).  Nothing worked.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things to try:

1. Are you **SURE** the `customerErrors` attribute is set correctly?  The
   Identity and Access tooling in Visual Studio seems to like to reset
   that back to `"Off"` (every time you update via the tool).
2. Are you able to connect to the role instance via Remote Desktop?  If
   so, you could inspect the `web.config` settings for the site? 
   Browsing to the site from the server might also provide a more
   friendly error message.
3. When you RDP into the cloud service, you can look at the Event
   Viewer to see the detailed error messages.

Comment: No, I'm not sure it's set correctly because I don't have remote access to look at the deployed web.config.  Not sure how to set that up, I'm new to Azure.  I can figure it out though.  I only used the ID&Access tool once and I changed it afterwards, so it shouldn't change it each time I do a package, should it?  If it does, then wouldn't my local copy of web.config reflect this?

Comment: Remote Desktop can be configured when you deploy the package via Visual Studio (there's an option in the deployment wizard to enable Remote Desktop support).  Alternatively, the management portal can now enable this feature too (w/o need for a redeploy).  If you want to see exactly what was deployed to the Azure instances, rename the .cspkg file to a .zip file and extract the contents.  Then find the .cssx (believe that's it - usually the largest file), rename that to .zip, and extract.  That will show you the files deployed to the Azure instances.

Comment: I've enabled RDP and navigated to the web.config, and its `customErrors` mode attribute is set to "Off"...

Comment: I took at look at the event viewer, and it's giving me what I need to know,

Comment: could you check out my other question I posted on Azure when you get a moment please?  I'd really appreciate it!!

Comment: Which question would that be?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17597181/azure-running-an-app-in-azure-using-adfs-returns-the-following-error-exceptio

Comment: you can check the web.config and even modify it in Azure using Kudu, if you have access to portal.azure.com.  Just go to your web app, then in the list of options, click "Advanced Tools" and then click "Go". In the top nav, click Debug console, then either CMD or Powershell. In the top, navigate to the wwwroot folder. You should see the web.config file now. Just click the little pen icon to edit it and voila!  You're in!

Comment: customerErrors should be customErrors

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this error by ftp'ing into my azure website and deleting the wwwroot folder and then publishing my website via visual studio.