# Azure - running an app in Azure using ADFS returns the following error: Exception message: ID4014: A SecurityTokenHandler is not

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, token, adfs2.0

I have my app built and deployed in Azure, utilizing ADFS for authentication.  When I access my app, it redirects me to the ADFS log-in page.  I log in, and then it redirects me back to my app, where I encounter the following exception:

> Exception information: 
>       Exception type: SecurityTokenException 
>       Exception message: ID4014: A SecurityTokenHandler is not registered to read security token ('BinarySecurityToken',
>   'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd').
>   at System.IdentityModel.Services.TokenReceiver.ReadToken(String
>   tokenXml, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas readerQuotas,
>   FederationConfiguration federationConfiguration)    at
>   System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SignInWithResponseMessage(HttpRequestBase
>   request)    at
>   System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object
>   sender, EventArgs args)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

**This is my first time dealing with ADFS and Azure - few questions:**

1. What part of my code would I need to modify to accommodate the
   Security Token requirement (assuming I need to)?  For example, when the user logs in through ADFS, and ADFS redirects the user back to my app, should my app "just work" at that point, and the Login link at the top of the page change to Logout?  I'm using MVC4.
2. My company's ADFS server has its own log-in page.  Does this mean I
   can do away with the log-in functionality that comes out of the box with my Azure
   MVC app?

**EDIT**
Here's the FederationMetadata.xml file with all sensitive data removed: http://mikemarks.net/FederationMetadata.xml

**EDIT**
Here's my `system.identityModel` and `system.identityModel.service` section of my web.config:

```
<system.identityModel>
  <identityConfiguration>
    <audienceUris>
      <add value="https://conocopocazuremike.cloudapp.net/" />
    </audienceUris>
    <!--Commented by Identity and Access VS Package-->
    <!--<issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry"><authority name="http://blah/adfs/services/trust"><keys><add thumbprint="blah" /></keys><validIssuers><add name="http://blah/adfs/services/trust" /></validIssuers></authority></issuerNameRegistry>-->
    <!--certificationValidationMode set to "None" by the the Identity and Access Tool for Visual Studio. For development purposes.-->
    <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />
    <!--Commented by Identity and Access VS Package-->
    <!--<issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry"><authority name="http://blah/adfs/services/trust"><keys><add thumbprint="blah" /></keys><validIssuers><add name="http://blah/adfs/services/trust" /></validIssuers></authority></issuerNameRegistry>-->
    <!--Commented by Identity and Access VS Package-->
    <!--<issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"><trustedIssuers><add thumbprint="blah" name="http://blah/adfs/services/trust" /></trustedIssuers></issuerNameRegistry>-->
    <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry">
      <authority name="http://blah/adfs/services/trust">
        <keys>
          <add thumbprint="blah" />
        </keys>
        <validIssuers>
          <add name="http://blah/adfs/services/trust" />
        </validIssuers>
      </authority>
    </issuerNameRegistry>
  </identityConfiguration>
</system.identityModel>
<system.identityModel.services>
  <federationConfiguration>
    <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" />
    <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="https://blah/adfs/ls/" realm="https://blah.cloudapp.net/" requireHttps="false" />
  </federationConfiguration>
</system.identityModel.services>
```

Comment: I honestly have no idea... is this the format that the token is sent in (JWT)?

Comment: @astaykov I am finding out right now

Comment: @astaykov I'm not sure.  Is that necessary to know to answer my question?

Comment: Are you using Azure ACS Access Control Service?

Comment: Ok, it would be good if you can share the way you configured ACS. My guess is that you are using a JWT or SWT token format and that's not supported out of the box on ASP.NET. SAML Tokens are.

Comment: @woloski Okay, forgive me, this is new to me... I am using ADFS... could someone be using ACS within ADFS?  I didn't configure the ADFS server, I'm just working with my Azure app to connect and authenticate against it.

Comment: @Carmine, It is necessary. You have to provide your entire `system.identityModel` and `system.identityModel.services` sections from web.config (probably omitting sensitive data like actual service addresses and certificate signatures). Also it is good know which exact endpoint of the ADFS are you using and with what type of Token. Indeed if ADFS is issuing `JWT` token, the chance to get "Security Token Handler is not configured ... (BinarySecurityToken)" is very big! JWT tokens are BASE64 encoded (which triggers that exception unless properly configured) while SAML and SWT are usually not.

Comment: I have another question - have you ever tried to run application outside Azure. Just run the MVC app federated to ADFS and running locally. Because the error is some configuration error and it is hard to say what is wrong without looking at both App `and` ADFS configuration. And I am 100% sure that you will get exactly the same error if you run your app on-premises, which eliminated the `Azure` tag totally. A complete FIDDLER dump of the whole round-trips between first call to the app and the last redirect from ADFS would also be helpful to identify the issue. Also `system.webServer` section.

Comment: @astaykov What I ended up doing was creating a VM on Azure, loading up and hosting a .NET website on it (integrated with ADFS), and I didn't get this error anymore.  The difference was in this example I used a "Cloud Service" template off of Azure's portal.  Honestly I don't know enough about Azure to know what technically the difference was between setting up a Cloud Service and just creating a VM and loading up a site at the server level... So, needless to say, I'm not going to investigate this error further for now.

Comment: @astaykov I don't know if I can award you the bounty without marking your answer as the correct answer (assuming you post an answer with all the information you've put).  If I can, I'll be more than happy to award you the bounty since you've been the most helpful...

Comment: Well, I am particularly interesting about this issue, as Cloud Service nothing essentially different then just a VM, so now you made it even more itching for me.

Comment: @astaykov One of the differences I've noticed is in Visual Studio, I created a Azure Cloud Service template (Web Role) and it came with the AzureWebRole project in my solution, which contained the service definition and configuration files.  In those, I had to define my SSL certificate.  I don't know if this particular project had anything to do with the issue.

Comment: Not really. You can also just use your Web MVC project, then right click and select "Add Azure Deployment Project", which will create Azure Cloud Service project with one Web Role pointing to your project. You will still need to add reference to your SSL Certificate for the web site. But the error is about SSL cert. It is about miss-matched token configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error

> ID4014: A SecurityTokenHandler is not registered to read security
>   token ('BinarySecurityToken',
>   'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd')

Usually pops out when your application received JWT token, and it is only configured to read SAML or SWT tokens. Other reason might be because a SAML token has been encrypted or binary encoded before sending back to the relying party.

First thing to check is whether both ends (ADFS and Relying Party Application) are configured for the same token type and that the RP (Relying Party) can read the configured token (SAML/SWT/JWT).

In order to fully understand configuration at the Relying party end we need to know following sections of `web.config` file: `system.identityModel`, `system.identityModel.services`, `system.webServer`. Along with that we also need the configuration of ADFS - how the relying party is configured at ADFS end. What endpoints are configured and what are used. The best tool to investigate is [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/).

And to eliminate that Azure is the issue, please verify that your application works correctly in on-premises environment.

Comment: Thanks for all the info!

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that in both the ends(ADFS & WIF) same token type is used.

Use SAML token for out of the box support from asp.net.

Can you post your federationMetadata.xml with certificate keys removed?

Comment: Yes I will do this on Monday. Thanks!

Comment: I cannot add my FederationMetadata.xml file's contents because the post is limited to 30,000 characters, and adding it would put it at 70,000.  Instead, here's the link to download it: http://mikemarks.net/FederationMetadata.xml

Comment: how do I know what format the token is in that gets sent from ADFS?

Comment: federationmetadata sais that: `fed:TokenTypesOffered`. SAML 2.0 and SAML 1.1 tokens. @Carmine, please also provide your application confgiration - `system.identityModel` and `system.identityModel.services` section.

Comment: @Carmine can you provide the federation metadata of ADFS along with the sytem.identityModel and system.identityModel.services part of web.config

Comment: @NavaRajan I edited my original post to include the web.config info you asked for.  Please see comment thread for the FederationMetadata.xml file location - it was too large to paste here.

Comment: @astaykov I updated my question to include the `system.identityModel` information.